# Replace property in template file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I`m new in JavaScript, so I want to ask you some question. I have file on server with template properties, for example it have: name = *some_name*, source=*some_source* and etc. I need to write a function which take 3 parametres: file location, new file location, **variables**. This function must open tempalte file, replace property to specific value from **variables**. So, result must be next: name=heloo, source = source1 and etc and save this file. How can I do this on JS?

```
fs.readFile(templateLocation,'utf8',function(err,contents){
fs.writeFile(newFileLocation,contents,function (err) {
  if(err){
    return console.log(err);
  }
    console.log("File saved!")
})});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you ask a question, you should show some effort toward researching and attempting this question on your own. Just as a heads up, you are likely to get downvotes on this question as a result. But to be helpful, read up a little bit in the Node.js Documentation on the 'FS' Module.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of template engine with caching. Either write it on your own or google up a library. We wont reinvent the wheel for you.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this. I already opened this file by 'fs' and wrote contents to new file. All I need now it`s set properties.